# Adding Joda Time

Tags: java, android, jodatime, noclassdeffounderror, libs

I am building an app that uses time. I decided to use Joda time. I am trying to add joda time to my app. I have no experience with adding `.jar` files to the libs. I followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105164/java-joda-time-download-and-install-step-by-step)(see bottom), or so I thought. My project is showing no errors, but when I run a simple test: `DateTime test = new DateTime();` I get a force close and the following error:

```
 Could not find class 'org.joda.time.DateTime', referenced from method xxxx
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.joda.time.DateTime
```

**These are the steps I followed:**

1. Create your android project in eclipse.
2. Download [Joda Time](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/)
3. In Eclipse look for your project at package explorer and right click on it then call it `New -> Folder -> libs`.  **Note: I did not do this because I already had a folder named `libs`**
4. Copy (or) drag & drop the `joda-time-2.1.jar` into the newly created `libs` folder.
5. Right click on your project again (in package explorer) then `Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Jars -> joda-time-2.1.jar`.

Now you can test with this code :

```
DateTime test = new DateTime();
```

After importing:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
```

Comment: clean the project and build.

Comment: you can start using jodatime, by adding the relevant import statement at the beginning of your class file (or just type DateTime for example, then CTRL+SPACE and eclipse should add the import for you)

Comment: Right. It is properly imported.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since it is an Android project, just referencing the Joda jar file won't do. You'll need to bundle that jar file along with your apk which can be done like this:-

1. Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export
2. Check on the `joda-time-*-*.jar` and click **Ok**. You're done.

---

**Explanation:** Referencing the jar alone will only solve the compilation issues in Eclipse (or any other IDE), but when the *apk* is created the "joda-time" jar file won't be exported/bundled along with your "apk". That is the reason why it throws the **NoClassDefFoundError**.

But when you check the joda-time jar in *Order & Export*, it'll make sure that the jar is also bundled inside/along with your "apk" whenever it is created.

Comment: Hallelujah!! That did it! Can you explain why i would need to do that for android?