# How to convert Date String to DateTime in Java?

Tags: java, date, datetime, type-conversion

I have a CSV file with a date string column. I want to spend the CSV data into mysql.

In CSV has a `String`: **"Sun Oct 05 20:59:57 BRT 2014"** and I want to convert to `DateTime`.

How do I do this?

Comment: You referring to Joda [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) or Java 8 [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)?

Comment: I have a csv file with a date string column. I want to spend the csv data into mysql.

Comment: Your question says `DateTime`, but Java doesn't have a built-in class with the name. There is a class with that name in the [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. Did you mean to say "DateTime", or are you asking about the built-in `java.util.Date`, or the newer `java.time.LocalDateTime`?

Comment: in mysql has the datetime type, I just need to pass the string to the format compatible.

Comment: So you want to parse the given string from the CSV file into a `java.sql.Timestamp` so it can be used on a `PreparedStatement.setTimestamp()` call, right? --- Please elaborate question.

Comment: @RogerRubens Check my answer, let me know it it's what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this `DateTimeFormat`

```
EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy
```

And now you should do this :

```
String string = "Sun Oct 05 20:59:57 BRT 2014";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date dt = formatter.parse(string);         //if you want to use DateTime do it DateTime dt = formatter.parse(string);
System.out.println(" Date " + datetime.toString());
```

### EDIT

First of all include those imports:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

Then your code should looks like as follows :

```
String string = "Sun Oct 05 20:59:57 BRT 2014";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
java.sql.Timestamp datetime = new Timestamp(formatter.parse(string).getTime());
System.out.println("DateTime: " + datetime.toString());
```

To use `DateTime` you should check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675173/adding-joda-time)

Comment: That's what I need. but I can't import DateTimeFormat and DateTime. Are you using the Joda?

Comment: Yes I saw it and fixes it before you commented :P

Comment: But now my answer is fine?

Comment: @RogerRubens Check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy   HH:mm:ss");

DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(string);
```

Comment: Format string doesn't match the question string.

Answer (score 0):

Try [DateTimeFormat](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(string);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252678/converting-a-date-string-to-a-datetime-object-using-joda-time-library) is similar question.