# Could not find class 'org.joda.time.DateTime', referenced from method ##

Tags: android, jodatime

Facing this issue since yesterday , searched a lot but didn't found any solution , can anybody help?

Getting following error:

```
Could not find class 'org.joda.time.DateTime', referenced from method com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.GeneratedDatabaseHolder.
```

Log:

```js
Could not find class 'org.joda.time.DateTime', referenced from method com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.GeneratedDatabaseHolder.<clinit>
06-01 11:10:16.521 8973-8973/org.hispindia.bidtrackerreports E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application org.hispindia.bidtrackerreports.HIApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException:
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675173/adding-joda-time

Comment: add this in your gradle section `compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'` .Then `clean-rebuild`

Comment: No same error is coming

Comment: not able to find :typeConverters.put(org.joda.time.DateTime.class, new org.hisp.dhis.android.sdk.persistence.converters.DateTimeConverter());    joda is in red color here  in generatedatabaseholder class

Comment: Following error is coming :Error:Could not find joda-time:joda-time-2.9.4:.
Required by:
    dhis2-android-tracker-reports:app:unspecified
<a href="searchInBuildFiles">Search in build.gradle files</a>

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android studio you can add

> compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'

**or** you can add joda-time-2.3.jar into lib folder.

In the file picker, just select the joda-time-2.3-sources.jar file. And you're done and add the line

> compile files('libs/joda-time-2.3.jar')

Comment: Error only comes for version 4.0 (api 14),  working fine on 5.0

Comment: Are you using latest version? https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/releases also put multiDexEnabled true in build.gradle and also you had to make custom Application extend MultiDexApplication

Comment: But why there is no error coming for 5.0 or api >19

Comment: It is on same link with title Multidex support prior to Android 5.0 and Is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I had multidex enabled in my .gradle, to resolve this issue I extended my Application with MultiDexApplication:

```
public class Application extends MultiDexApplication
```

For more information refer to the developer guide:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html